# Can "Invoke_endpoint" calls timeout a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am attempting to pass json data into my sagemaker model through a lambda function. Currently, I am using a testing model that makes relatively quick inferences and returns them to the lambda function through the invoke_endpoint call. However, eventually a more advanced model will be implemented which might take longer than a lambda function can fun for (15 minutes maximum) to produce inferences. In the case that I call invoke_endpoint in one lambda function, can I return the response to another lambda function which is invoked by the sagemaker endpoint response? Even better, can I shut down the current lambda function after sending the data to sagemaker, and re-invoke it upon a response? I need to store the inference in DynamoDB, which is why I need a response (Unless I can update the saved model to store inferences directly, in which case I need the lambda function to not expect a response from invoke_endpoint). Sorry for my ignorance, I am a bit new to sagemaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `invoke_endpoint`, the underlying model invocation must take [less than 1 minute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-code-how-containe-serves-requests). If a single model execution needs more time to execute, consider running the model in Lambda itself, in SageMaker Training API (if its coldstart is acceptable) or in a custom service. If the invocation is made of several shorter calls you can also chain multiple services together with Step Functions.